# undefine variable in FileDownloader.php

Tags: php

I got some notice said there are `undefined variable: ShowErrorPage in C:\xampp\htdocs\dwupload\FileDownloader.php on line 18` and also `undefined variable: ErrorMsg in C:\xampp\htdocs\dwupload\FileDownloader.php on line 39`

Here I show my upload, download and view file:

1. FileUploader.php

   UploadFile

   ```
   <body>

   <?php

   $Dir = "files";
   if (isset($_FILES['new_file'])) {
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_file']['tmp_name'], $Dir . "/" . $_FILES['new_file']['name']) == TRUE) {
           chmod($Dir . "/" . $_FILES['new_file']['name'], 0644);
           echo "File \"" . htmlentities($_FILES['new_file']['name']) . "\"successfully uploaded. <br />\n";
       }
       else 
           echo "There was an error uploading \"" . htmlentities($_FILES['new_file']['name']) . "\" .<br />\n";
   }

   ?>

   <form action="FileUploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="25000"/><br />
       File to upload: <br />
       <input type="file" name="new_file" /><br /> (25,000 byte limit) <br />
       <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload The File" />
       <br />
   </form>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
2. ViewFile.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ViewFile</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <?php 
    
    $Dir = "files";
    $DirEntries = scandir($Dir);
    foreach ($DirEntries as $Entry) {
     if ((strcmp($Entry, '.') != 0) && (strcmp($Entry, '..') != 0))
     echo "<a href=\"FileDownloader.php?filename=$Entry\">". htmlentities($Entry). "</a><br />\n";
     
    }
    
    ?>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

3. FileDownloader.php

```html
<?php

$Dir = "files";
if (isset($_GET['filename'])) {
 $FileToGet = $Dir . "/" . stripcslashes($_GET['filename']);
 if (is_readable($FileToGet)) {
 }
 else {
  $ErrorMsg = "Cannot read \"$FileToGet\"";
  $ShowErrorPage = TRUE;
 }
}
else {
 $ErrorMsg = "No filename specifified";
 $ShowErrorPage = TRUE;
}

if ($ShowErrorPage) {
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $_GET['filename'] . "\"");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64");
 header("Content-Length: " . filesize($FileToGet));
 readfile($FileToGet);
 $ShowErrorPage = FALSE;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>DownloadFile</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>
<p>There was an error downloading "<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['filename']); ?></p>
<p><?php echo htmlentities($ErrorMsg); ?></p>




</body>

</html>
```

Do anyone know why it give me the notice? And there was no error in `FileDownloader.php` but when I try to download the file i upload using `FileUploader.php` and it said there was an error while uploading come with the notice. Anyone can help me? I'm still new in php and I need someone to guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare these variables with a default value before directly assign values in conditional statements.
In the begining of the file add this

```
$ShowErrorPage = TRUE;
$ErrorMsg = '';
```